# Avoid duplication when using React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm using React context for state management and code climate doesn't like the repetition around Context Providers.

[image]

Is there any way that I can remove the duplication?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a duplication to me as both context providers are providing a specific part of state. I find it readable this way and will rather relax the CodeClimate rule. You can however implement a high order component that wraps child component in a generic react provider and receives provider values as props.

Comment: Sorry, 'Similar code' was the exact phrasing I think. Can you elaborate on the hoc approach by any chance? I don't understand how I would create make one generic provider with different values as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code climate rule can be relaxed for this particular code.

That said, you can transform the current usage of context to a React component exposing its props as a channel to provide values in a generic context provider.

For example, a `WithCollection` component which forwards its props to a generic `CollectionContext.Provider` can be created. The consolidates the function `TasksContext.Provider` and `CommentsContext.Provider` in `CollectionContext.Provider`.

```
class WithCollection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {children, ...value} = this.props
    return (
      <CollectionContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      </CollectionContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The usage of which is represented as follow:

```
<WithCollection tasks={this.state.tasks}>
//...
</WithCollection>
```